# WorksheetFunction.Average and paste to new sheet

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

I have a set of data on sheet1 and I'm trying to take the average of every 48 values and paste it onto sheet2. I'm getting a run-time error '1004': Unable to get the Average property of the WorksheetFunction class. I tried searching for different solutions but unable to come up with one. Can I get some help with my code. My code worked when it was simply taking the average and pasting on the same sheet.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim j As Long, i As Long, irow As Integer, lastrow1 As Long, lastcol1 As Long

lastrow1 = Range(Sheets("HalfHour").Cells(5, 5), Sheets("HalfHour").Cells(5, 5).End(xlDown)).Count
lastcol1 = Range(Sheets("HalfHour").Cells(5, 5), Sheets("HalfHour").Cells(5, 5).End(xlToRight)).Count
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    With Worksheets("Daily")
        For j = 5 To lastcol + 5
            For i = 5 To lastrow1 + 5 Step 48
                wb.Worksheets("Daily").Cells(irow, a - 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(wb.Worksheets("HalfHour").Range(Cells(i, j), Cells(i + 47, j)))
                irow = irow + 1
            Next i
            If Cells(i, j).Value = "" Then
                GoTo done
            End If
        Next j
    End With
```

done:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write following loop

```
For i = 5 To lastrow1 + 5 Step 48
    wb.Worksheets("Daily").Cells(irow, a - 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(wb.Worksheets("HalfHour").Range(Cells(i, j), Cells(i + 47, j)))
    irow = irow + 1
Next i
```

as

```
For i = 5 To lastrow1 + 5 Step 48
    Set myRange = Range(wb.Worksheets("HalfHour").Cells(i, j), wb.Worksheets("HalfHour").Cells(i, j).Cells(i + 47, j))
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(myRange) > 0 Then
        wb.Worksheets("Daily").Cells(irow, a - 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(myRange)
    End If
    irow = irow + 1
Next i
```

**Note:** Write `Dim myRange As Range` where you are declaring your variables.

You can write complete code as:

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim j As Long, i As Long, irow As Integer, lastrow1 As Long, lastcol1 As Long
    Dim myRange As Range

    irow = 1
    a = 2

    lastrow1 = Range(Sheets("HalfHour").Cells(5, 5), Sheets("HalfHour").Cells(5, 5).End(xlDown)).Count
    lastcol1 = Range(Sheets("HalfHour").Cells(5, 5), Sheets("HalfHour").Cells(5, 5).End(xlToRight)).Count
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    For j = 5 To lastcol + 5
        For i = 5 To lastrow1 + 5 Step 48
            Set myRange = Range(wb.Worksheets("HalfHour").Cells(i, j), wb.Worksheets("HalfHour").Cells(i, j).Cells(i + 47, j))
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(myRange) > 0 Then
                wb.Worksheets("Daily").Cells(irow, a - 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(myRange)
            End If
            irow = irow + 1
        Next i
        If Cells(i, j).Value = "" Then
            GoTo done
        End If
    Next j
done:
End Sub
```

This code will display the averages for the sets of 48 rows in Sheet `Daily` in `Column A`.

Comment: This code works great, however, there needs to be a small tweak for the average
`Set myRange = Range(wb.Worksheets("HalfHour").Cells(i, j), wb.Worksheets("HalfHour").Cells(i, j).Cells(i + 47, j))`
should be
`Set myRange = Range(wb.Worksheets("HalfHour").Cells(i, j), wb.Worksheets("HalfHour").Cells(i + 47, j))`

but I don't quite understand how to use myRange, could you explain why coding it this way works but mine doesn't?